# Bound datagrid not showing values

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bound to a binding source which itself is populated from a list.

I can see that the binding source is populated and I can see that the datagrid has the expected number of rows to match the data in the list but i can not get the columns to populate with the data.  I have tried setting the datapropertyname for the columns but to no avail.  I know this is probably dead simple but I'm going round in circles.

Please can anyone help

Dim cE As New ClsEmail

```
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim dgv = Me.DataGridView1

    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    bs.DataSource = cE.GetMail("team@xxxx.xxxx")

    With dgv.Columns(0)
        .DataPropertyName = "ID"
        .HeaderText = "ID"

    End With

    With dgv.Columns(1)
        .DataPropertyName = "Subject"
        .HeaderText = "Subject"
    End With

    dgv.DataSource = bs
```

When i press the button to populate the datagrid I get four rows but no values in the columns.  Clearly I'm not binding the columns correctly but i can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure that the .DataPropertyNames of ID and Subject are the exact same spelling as field names on your DataSource?

Comment: Yes.  The datapropertyname of the source data are created

Comment: I am generating the data by reading an outlook mail box and creating a new class with three properties, ID, Subject and DataReceived and then i use these same names as the dataperoptynames, same spelling, same case

Comment: Try setting dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true to see what shows on the grid, it might give you a hint.

Comment: What does `cE.GetMail("team@xxxx.xxxx")` return? There's also no reason to declare `dgv` (especially without a type), just use DataGridView1 directly. You're also setting the `.DataSource` property twice. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: dgv.autogenerate doesn't do anything

Comment: ce.GetMail returns a List. 

Dim list As New List(Of Email) which is 
    
Public Class Email
        Public Subject As String
    Public DateReceived As DateTime
    Public ID As Integer

i can see the list in the locals debug window and see all the rows.  the datagrid adds the correct number of rows but the columns themselves aren't binding to the underlying data.

i used dgv just whilst tinkering.

I don't see where I'm setting the datasource twice. once to the binding source and then the binding source to the datagrid.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong but i can't see it myself

Comment: @HardCode "You're also setting the .DataSource property twice. " The OP sets the BindingSource.DataSource and DataGridView.DataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List(Of T) is already bindable. Rearrange your properties in your Email class like this, as the DataGridView will create the columns in property order:

```
Public Class Email 

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Subject As String 
    Public Property DateReceived As DateTime 

End Class
```

Then, just set the datasource like this:

```
With DataGridView1

    .AutoGenerateColumns = True
    .DataSource = cE.GetMail("team@xxxx.xxxx")
    .Columns(2).Visible = False ' DataReceived (if you really intended to hide this)

End With
```

Comment: Good catch! Updated answer (modified the code for Class Email).